# Sort list merged with 2 different pojos according to date

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my pojo class

```
inner class Data : Serializable {
    var abc: ArrayList<ABC>? = null
    var xyz: ArrayList<XYZ>? = null

    inner class XYZ : Serializable {
        var x: String? = null
        var date: String? = null
    }

    inner class ABC : Serializable {
        var a: String? = null
        var date: String? = null
    }
}
```

I want to merge the ABC and XYZ arraylist in one list and sort that list according to date

so far ,I have done this

```
val items = ArrayList<Any>()
items.addAll(data!!.xyz!!)   
items.addAll(data!!.abc!!)
```

And getting merged list like this

```
x (from XYZ arraylist in descending order)
x (from XYZ arraylist in descending order)
x (from XYZ arraylist in descending order)
a (from ABC arraylist in descending order)
a (from ABC arraylist in descending order)
a (from ABC arraylist in descending order)
```

But what I want is sort the whole list according to date

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to introduce an interface `WithDate` and let your classes implement it.

```
interface WithDate {
    val date: String?
}

inner class XYZ : Serializable, WithDate {
    var x: String? = null
    override var date: String? = null
}
```

Now you have a list of `WithDate` and you can use the `sortBy` function.

```
val list = ArrayList<WithDate>()
...
list.sortBy(WithDate::date)
```

If you can't change the classes, go with this:

```
val list = ArrayList<Any>()
list.sortBy {
    when(it) {
        is Data.XYZ -> it.date ?: ""
        is Data.ABC -> it.date ?: ""
        else -> ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Collections.sort to sort your list.
Step 1:
When you merge your list use this

```
   Collections.sort(<UR LIST>, new compareMethod());
```

Step 2:
Create compareMethod();

```
class compareMethod implements Comparator<LISTNAME> {
    @Override
    public int compare(LISTNAME object1, LISTNAME object2) {
        return object1.getDate().compareTo(object2.getDate());
    }
}
```

hope you understand.

Comment: I have already tried this but it does not works with my case. It will work when we to sort in same object class.

Answer (score 0):

please try with below methods. Hope it will solve your problem.

First Take one common pojo class like below

```
class MergedResponse : Serializable {

var data: Data? = null

inner class Data : Serializable {

@SerializedName(value = "xyz", alternate = arrayOf("abc"))
var mCommon: ArrayList<Common>? = null

inner class Common : Serializable {
        var x: String? = null
        var a: String? = null
        var date: String? = null
        }
    }
}
```

And then write below code in your class

```
val mainData = Gson().toJson(data!!)
var mJsonXYZ: JSONObject = JSONObject(mainData)
var mJsonABC: JSONObject = JSONObject(mainData)
mJsonXYZ.remove("abc")
mJsonABC.remove("xyz")

val mypojoXYZ = Gson().fromJson<MergedResponse.Data>(Gson().toJson(Gson().fromJson<Data>(mJsonXYZ.toString(), Data::class.java)), MergedResponse.Data::class.java)

val mypojoABC = Gson().fromJson<MergedResponse.Data>(Gson().toJson(Gson().fromJson<Data>(mJsonABC.toString(), Data::class.java)), MergedResponse.Data::class.java)

val itemsXYZ = ArrayList<MergedResponse.Data.Common>()
itemsXYZ.addAll(mypojoXYZ.mCommon!!)
itemsXYZ.addAll(mypojoABC.mCommon!!)


Collections.sort(itemsXYZ, object : Comparator<MergedResponse.Data.Common> {
    override fun compare(object1: MergedResponse.Data.Common, object2: MergedResponse.Data.Common): Int {
    return object1.date!!.compareTo(object2.date!!)
}
})
```